# Kotlin - Parse JSON

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin

I have a json string with 2 keys `error` and `user`. First I want to check if `error` is not `false` and get the values from `user`.

Here is the Json String:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "user": {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "Someone",
        "email": "someone@gmail.com",
        "aktif": 1
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Get the `jsonObject` "error" first : `JSONObject errorCheck = yourjsonresult.getJSONObject("error");`
then compare to check if it is false or not. (by using `Boolean`)

Comment: Thats ok but how can I get the values from `user` array ?

Comment: Check my answer. Also, there are no arrays in there.

Comment: My bad.. It supposed to be object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `JsonObject` "error" first :

```
val errorCheck = yourjsonresult.getJSONObject("error");
```

Then compare to check if it was `false` then:

```
if(errorCheck.equals("false")) { // or if it wasn't false -> !errorCheck.equals("false"))

    val data = yourjsonresult.getJsonObject("user"); // get the user object
    val name = data?.getString("name"); // or the other items
}
```

The result should be:

```
Someone
```

Also, arrays starts by `[` but in your case, those are json objects which starts-ends by `{}`.